# Is correct to use `dynamic_cast` to infer the type of an argument of a member function defined on the base class and implemented on a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

I am just starting with C++. I am trying to design a class(interface) for a subset of vector operations. This [abstract base class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_concrete) is defined as:

```
// File: vect.hh
#ifndef _vect_hh
#define _vect_hh

class vect
{
    public:
        virtual double norm() const = 0;
        virtual void   add(const double scaleThis, const double scaleOther,
                           const vect& other) = 0;
        virtual double dot(const vect& other) const = 0;
        virtual vect* clone() const = 0;
        virtual vect* copy(const vect& other) const = 0;
        virtual ~vect() = default;
};
#endif
```

The problems appears in the functions that has as argument `const vect& other`. Since in the derived class what I really want is something like
`const vectDerived& other` as argument. To exemplify the problem I made a simple implementation of the previous class using raw pointers. Because I have some others problems that I going to comment at the end of this question, I have inserted the full definition of the class. But keep in mind the most important functions are `dot` and `add`:

```
// File: vectDouble.hh
#ifndef _vectDouble_hh
#define _vectDouble_hh

#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

#include "vect.hh"

class vectDouble: public vect
{
public:
    explicit vectDouble(const int n): n{n}, elem{new double[n]}
    {
        std::memset(elem, '\0', sizeof(double)*n);
    }

    ~vectDouble() override {delete[] elem;}

    vectDouble(const vectDouble& other): n{other.n}, elem{new double[n]}
    {
        std::memcpy(elem, other.elem, n*sizeof(double));
    }

    vectDouble& operator = (const vectDouble& other)
    {
        if(&other != this)
        {
            delete[] elem; n = other.n;
            elem = new double[n];
            std::memcpy(elem, other.elem, sizeof(double)*n);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    vectDouble(vectDouble&& other): n{0}, elem{nullptr}
    {
        fillClass(other, *this);
    }

    vectDouble &operator = (vectDouble&& other)
    {
        if(&other != this)
        {
            delete[] elem;
            fillClass(other, *this);
            other.elem = nullptr; other.n = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    double norm() const override
    {
        double norm = 0.0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            norm += elem[i]*elem[i];
        }
        return std::sqrt(norm);
    }

    double dot(const vect& other) const override
    {
        const vectDouble &v = dynamic_cast<const vectDouble&>(other);
        double dot = 0.0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            dot += elem[i]*v.elem[i];
        }
        return dot;
    }

    void add (const double scaleThis, const double scaleOther,
          const vect& other) override
    {
        const vectDouble &v = dynamic_cast<const vectDouble&>(other);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            elem[i] = scaleThis*elem[i] + scaleOther*v.elem[i];
        }
    }

    double& operator[](const int i){return elem[i];}

    const double& operator[](const int i) const {return elem[i];}

    int size() const{return n;}

    vectDouble* clone() const override
    {
        return new vectDouble(*this);
    }

    vectDouble* copy(const vect& other) const override
    {
        const vectDouble &v = dynamic_cast<const vectDouble&>(other);
        auto *t = new vectDouble(*this);
        t->n = v.n;
        std::memcpy(t->elem, v.elem, t->n*sizeof(double));
        return t;
    }

private:
    void fillClass(const vectDouble& in, vectDouble& out)
    {
        out.n = in.n; out.elem = in.elem;
    }

    int n;
    double *elem;
};
#endif
```

In both functions I used `const vectDouble &v = dynamic_cast<const vectDouble&>(other);` to convert the base class reference to a reference with type of the derived class. This is a valid use case for the `dynamic_cast`. If not, what is the proper way to achieve this result?

I have remarked that I have run in other problems (sorry for straying away of the main question). As example of use of the abstract class and of the previous implementation I made this simple and somewhat contrived main program:

```
// File main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "vectDouble.hh"

double lsfit(const vect& dobs, const vect& dcalc)
{
    std::unique_ptr<vect> tmp(dcalc.copy(dcalc));

    return (dobs.dot(dcalc))/(dcalc.dot(*tmp));
}

void testFit()
{
    vectDouble d{10};
    vectDouble x{10};

    for(int i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
    {
        d[i] = static_cast<double>(3*i);
        x[i] = static_cast<double>(i);
    }
    std::cout << "alpha=" << lsfit(d, x) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    testFit();
    return 0;
}
```

This program illustrates one use case envisioned for the interface described. However, without the use of the `std::unique_ptr`, there is a memory leak (identified using the option `-fsanitize=leak` from the g++compiler). If, *instead* of using the *unique_ptr*, I wanted to manually manage the memory (as curiosity), what is the proper way to clean up this result? Is it possible to return a `std::unique_ptr` directly from the copy function? When I tried to do this, I received error messages relative to wrong covariant return types.

Remarks:

1. The intent of this interface is to abstract the storage scheme used to represent the arrays, for instance a file instead of an in-memory representation.
2. I am aware that the copy function presented is more akin to create/clone plus a copy function.
3. Is the structure presented adequate if, in the future, I wanted to use templates in both the base and derived classes? For instance, `template<float> class vect{...}` and `template <float> class vectDerived{...}`?

Following [the advice of hayt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588196/is-correct-to-use-dynamic-cast-to-infer-the-type-of-an-argument-of-a-member-fu/39588713#39588713), I have changed the definitions of both `vect.hh` and `vectDouble.hh` to use the [CRTP pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) described. After these changes, I also changed the definition of the function *lsftit* to:

```
template <class Derived> double lsfit2(const Derived& dobs, const Derived& dcalc)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> tmp = dcalc.clone();
    Derived *t = tmp.get();
    t->copy(dcalc);
    return (dobs.dot(dcalc))/(dcalc.dot(*t));
}
```

Is this a proper way to define this function when using this pattern?

Comment: Imagine you have a vector with `double` and with `int`. What do you want to happen when e.g. `dot` gets a vector with a different type in it, like vec<double> gets vec<int> as `other` param?

Comment: For your clone function, look at [Prototype pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/5867/prototype-pattern/20640/prototype-pattern-c#t=201609200745552945624). but your `vect` abstraction is strange.

Comment: Your  `dynamic_cast` is problematic (and/or your interface is). Suppose that you have `vectDouble` and `vectDouble2`, how do you use them together from `vect` interface ?

Comment: @hayt in this case I want a nice error message =). I am thinking more in terms of single/double precision and real/complex variables. thanks

Comment: @ Jarod42  What is the meaning of vectDouble2 ? What is strange in the interface. The use case that I have in mind is to use this vector class for instance to write some linear algebra algorithms (think conjugate gradients) and for these type of algorithms in general only these operations are necessary. Do you have any recommendation in how  I can change the abstraction? thanks

Comment: @AlanSouza in your case you get an exception though. I answered with an solution which should make it impossible to assigne incompatible vectors to each other.

Comment: You have an interface and may have several concrete classes implementing this interface. How does `add` can be implemented with your interface ? It requires element getter, size getter. (but then `add`, `dot` should probably not be `virtual` anymore).

Comment: @Jarod42 If  I understood correctly you are concerned with respect to the iteration and access of elements of vect? Is that correct? The intent that I have with this class is really to shield the functions that are going to call  the functions defined in `vect.hh` from the process of filling/defining and iterating the arrays. I expect these operations to be made elsewhere. For instance in the function `lsfit`  the arrays `d` and `x` they are not accessed directly from this function only the internal product of both arrays. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm concerned on how to implement `MyClass::dot(const vect& other) override` with `vect` interface. It seems that I need to know the dynamic type of `vect`. It seems you use interface to give contract to type accepted by `lsfit`. **Concept** are not part of C++ yet, but it should solve this issue. But `lsfit` would require to be templated in that case.

Comment: This usage is not correct, you cannot assume that just because the base class is vect that you can cast it to vectDouble.  dynamic cast can return nullptr

    `double dot(const vect& other) const override
    {
        const vectDouble &v = dynamic_cast<const vectDouble&>(other);`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you really need inheritance and maybe switch to one generic vector class with a template parameter (from you only have "double" as something specific)

An alternative would be using CRTP in combination with declaring an interface. (I also added the unique_ptr in this apporach)

```
template <class Derived>
class vect
{
  public:
      virtual double norm() const = 0;
      virtual void   add(const double scaleThis, const double scaleOther,
                         const Derived& other)  = 0;
      virtual double dot(const Derived& other) const = 0;
      virtual std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const = 0;
      virtual std::unique_ptr<Derived> copy(const vect& other) const = 0;
      virtual ~vect()=default;
};
```

This way you have the same "interface" but a different "base class" and you have the derived class also in your functions here. So you will not have to worry about assigning "incompatible" vectors to each other via the interfaces (see dynamic_cast).

Additionally you can later derive the class for further specifications.

Here is what you class would look like with this approach:

```
class vectDouble: public vect<vectDouble>
{
public:
    //...
    //NOTE: here vecDouble is a parameter. no need for dynamic casts
    double dot(const vectDouble& other) const override
    {        
        double dot = 0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){dot += elem[i]*other.elem[i];}
        return dot;
    }
    void add (const double scaleThis, const double scaleOther,
          const vectDouble& other) override
    {

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                elem[i] = scaleThis*elem[i] + scaleOther*other.elem[i];
        }
    }
    //also directly a unique pointer
    std::unique_ptr<vectDouble> clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<vectDouble>(*this);
    }
    //...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Appears to be what I was looking for. If I wanted to define the copy/move operators for this derived class `class vectDouble: public vect<vectDouble>` is necessary to take any extra precautions?

Comment: depends on your class. But you should only be able to have the same type as `other` parameter so there should be no difference to the usual approach you would do with other classes.

Comment: I have followed your advice and updated the question with regards to changes to the function `lsfit`. Feedback would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Why CRTP? What  does it bring to the table? Just Don't Do It. There's not a single reason to use it here. Use templates.

Comment: Hi @n.m. What are you suggesting exactly? To use classes only in the definition of functions, like in the case of function lsfit2 (I have updated the answer)? If I not mistaken in this case I will lose the ability to enforce a interface, is this correct?

Comment: @AlanSouza I suggest you look at std::vector. Is there any problem with enforcing its interface, whatever that means?

Comment: @n.m. I mentioned in the beginning of the answer that simply templates may be the way to go, but offered a CRTP approach if (for whatever reason) he needed some base-interface class.

Comment: @AlanSouza it is not really a good practice on stackoverflow to edit your question after an answer and follow up with another question. For your `lsfit2` question. You can achieve the same without using an interface class just by using templates (the error messages may just look more cryptic)